# proxing request trough nginx isn't working, error 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have following nginx configuration

```
upstream backend {
  server backendserver01.example.com;
}

server
{
        listen 8097;
        listen [::]:8097;
        server_name  mynginxproxy.domain.local;

        location /
        {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
}
```

I run following curl command:

```
curl -v -g -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "X-API-KEY: some-guid" --URL "http://mynginxproxy.domain.local:8097/path/api/v1/getData?exported=false&component[name]=somecomponent"
```

I received a 404 from the nginx.

Running the command directly against the backendserver01.example.com works completly fine.
any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using incorrect config:

```
server_name  _;
```

Because you are curling on `mynginxproxy.domain.local` which means that you are using Server name indication, like passing the host header to Nginx, and Nginx is not currently configured to accept requests on `mynginxproxy.domain.local` virtual host.

Change this line to:

```
server_name  mynginxproxy.domain.local;
```

Remove unnecessary line `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` from location section, because you are proxying http and not https.

And be sure that `mynginxproxy.domain.local` FQDN is correctly resolving on Nginx host.

Comment: I have updated my configuration, but the problem still exists

Comment: Try adding host header in curl request, like: -H 'Host: mynginxproxy.domain.local'  and test again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the solution.

setting

```
proxy_set_header Host backendserver01.example.com;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

solved my issue.